# "Fully static" HD63B09EP loses state when clock is paused

Tags: microcontroller

The [HD6309](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_6309) is supposed to be a fully static replacement for the MC6809, where "fully static" means that the clock frequency does not have a lower limit. The MC6809 gets the electronics-equivalent of amnesia when the clock is too slow. The HD6309 - supposedly - works fine with slow clocks and - supposedly - the clock can also be paused indefinitely.

I bought a few HD63B09EP on ebay to experiment with. (B = maximum bus frequency of 2MHz (i.e. 8MHz clock frequency), E = External clock generation, P = PDIP package)
I put it on a breadboard, with red LEDs on pins A0 to A7, yellow LEDs on pins A8 to A15 and blue LEDs on pins Q, E, R/!W, BA and BS.
The big button on the left makes an ATtiny85 output the two clock signals E and Q, where Q leads E. The big button on the right connects to !RESET.
1.5k resistors pull the data bus to 0x12, so after a reset, the controller jumps to 0x1212 and increments its address from there. 0x12 is also the NOP instruction, nothing really is happening aside from the address bus counting up.

If the clock is paused only for a short moment, things continue fine afterwards. A few seconds of pause usually cause the address bus to go 0xFFFF for a moment and then continue normally. Longer pauses cause all sorts of weirdness, like the LEDs on the address bus slowly lighting up, flashing LEDs, or the address bus going high impedance and BA coming high, which can only be remedied by a reset. Here's a video of some of the symptoms: https://puu.sh/EVJET/086da059e6.mp4

Inspiration for this was a video by Ben Eater: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnzuMJLZRdU
He uses a 6502-type controller which is also "fully static" and it seems to have no problem with the clock not running. (Can be seen especially well from 22:42 onwards in that video.)
As far as I understand, this should not happen. Did I just stumble upon cheap "knock off" chips? Or is this behavior to be expected? The datasheet does indeed specify 2MHz minimum clock frequency (which equates to 500kHz bus frequency) but how can it then be advertised as "fully static"?

Comment: It sounds like you did not choose a reputable supplier for your parts. You may have received fake parts or parts that failed the "stop-the-clock" test.

Comment: Can you point to a datasheet that says it being fully static? I only found a HD63B09E datasheet that does not mention it being static and had maximum clock period mentioned.

Comment: How much current does the chip draw when not clocked? Can you show us the schematic of your circuit?

Comment: I don't always trust Wikipedia, but when I do, they're wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_6309 Under "Process Technology" it says "It is also a fully static device, which will not lose internal state information."

Comment: @BruceAbbott After a reset and during clocking (at the equivalent of around 20Hz, i.e. 5Hz bus frequency) the chip uses around 0.1mA. The moment I stop the clock, the current slowly ramps up to around 12mA, lingers a while and then starts going up and down. I've seen peeks of 44mA.

Comment: Well that's good news because it means you have a real HD6309, not a 'fake' (ie. relabeled 6809). The slowly ramping up current suggests floating inputs, either on pins, or inside the chip (which would prove that it isn't fully static - as expected from the datasheet). Any chance of seeing that schematic?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I forgot to mention that I removed all LEDs and the resistors on the data bus pins from the breadboard for that test. There's really not much else going on in the schematic: https://puu.sh/EW0ja/b641d60de1.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not static

The minimum f.XTAL is 2MHz

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. Someone called Lamune added that claim to Wikipedia in 2006. I wonder where they got that information from. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hitachi_6309&oldid=48448210 In any case, I'm now wondering whether there **is** a fully static version of the MC6809.

Answer (score 0):

MC68SEC000 is fully static -> https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/98037/MOTOROLA/MC68SEC000/+77148UILSxSPME+SpDGbxMCwD+/datasheet.pdf

see section 2.4 at the bottom of page 4

but it is 6800 not 6809

Comment: And the question was not about the 6809, but about the 6309.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson That's not the problem. The 6309 is an extension of the 6809. I am fine with either of those, as long as it's fully static. Unfortunately, 6800 does not work for me.

Comment: @NikoO While the 6309 and 6809 may have a closely related architecture and instruction set, they are very different animals electrically.